# How can I "grep" patterns across multiple lines?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, search, file-search

It seems I am misusing `grep`/`egrep`.

I was trying to search for strings in multiple line and could not find a match while I know that what I'm looking for should match. Originally I thought that my regexes were wrong but I eventually read that these tools operate per line (also my regexes were so trivial it could not be the issue).

So which tool would one use to search patterns across multiple lines?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiline pattern match using sed, awk or grep](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/multiline-pattern-match-using-sed-awk-or-grep)

Comment: @CiroSantilli - I do not think that this Q and the one you linked to are duplicates. The other Q is asking how you'd do multi-line pattern match (i.e. what tool should/can I use to do this) while this one is asking how to do this with `grep`. They are tightly related but not dups, IMO.

Comment: @sim those cases are hard to decide: I can see your point. I think this particular case is better as a duplicate because the user said `"grep"` suggesting the verb "to grep", and top answers, including accepted, don't use grep.

Comment: There is no indication to show that a multi-line regular expression is needed here. Please consider showing an actual example with input data and expected output data, as well as your previous effort.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here's a `sed` one that will give you `grep`-like behavior across multiple lines:

```
sed -n '/foo/{:start /bar/!{N;b start};/your_regex/p}' your_file
```

**How it works**

- `-n` suppresses the default behavior of printing every line
- `/foo/{}` instructs it to match `foo` and do what comes inside the squigglies to the matching lines. Replace `foo` with the starting part of the pattern.
- `:start` is a branching label to help us keep looping until we find the end to our regex.
- `/bar/!{}` will execute what's in the squigglies to the lines that don't match `bar`. Replace `bar` with the ending part of the pattern.
- `N` appends the next line to the active buffer (`sed` calls this the pattern space)
- `b start` will unconditionally branch to the `start` label we created earlier so as to keep appending the next line as long as the pattern space doesn't contain `bar`.
- `/your_regex/p` prints the pattern space if it matches `your_regex`. You should replace `your_regex` by the whole expression you want to match across multiple lines.

Comment: Note: On MacOS this gives `sed: 1: "/foo/{:start /bar/!{N;b ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)`

Comment: Getting `sed: unterminated {` error

Comment: @Nomaed Shot in the dark here, but does your regex happen to contain any "{" characters? If so, you'll need to backslash-escape them.

Comment: Nope. I got it both on Mac and in a BusyBox image. Didn't try GNU Linux.

Comment: Just ran it on CentOS and it worked fine though

Comment: @Nomaed It seems that it has to do with [the differences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13716/26909) between `sed` implementations. I tried to follow the recommendations in that answer to make the above script standard-compliant but it told me that "start" was an undefined label. So I'm not sure whether this can be done in a standard-compliant way. If you do manage it, please feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: IINM this doesn't work if `foo` and `bar` are the same. `sed -n '/^_$/{:start /^_$/!{N;b start};/.*/p}' your_file` just prints a bunch of underscores for me (on `sed (GNU sed) 4.5`).

Comment: @JosephR.: How can I specify bar to be a simple regex. For example, my text is something like this "TRANSLATION
The great sage Maitreya told Vidura: When the king entered his city, 
PURPORT". However, sometimes, it can be like this. "TRANSLATION
Fragrant xxxx
SB". In this case, the "bar", instead of being "PURPORT" is "SB". How can I tell sed that the "bar" can either be "PURPORT" or "SB". Thanks

Comment: I tried using the command "sed -n '/TRANSLATION/{:start /PURPORT/!{N;b start};/.*/p}'" -- it works most of the time but sometimes, as I mentioned above, instead of TRANSLATION at the end of the text, it has "SB". So, if you could let me know how to do something like this "TRANSLATION|SB" or equivalent, that will be great. Thanks.

Comment: @anjanb Have you tried `PURPORT\|SB`?

Comment: @JosephR. : Thanks. I didn't earlier. I tried now but sed throws an error. I'm running on windows, if that helps and sed(v 4.4) comes from cygwin.

Answer (score 26):

I generally use a tool called `pcregrep` which can be installed in most of the linux flavour using `yum` or `apt`.

For eg.

Suppose if you have a file named `testfile` with content

```
abc blah
blah blah
def blah
blah blah
```

You can run the following command:

```
$ pcregrep -M  'abc.*(\n|.)*def' testfile
```

to do pattern matching across multiple lines.

Moreover, you can do the same with `sed` as well.

```
$ sed -e '/abc/,/def/!d' testfile
```

Comment: this `sed` suggestion skips the line where `def` would be found

Answer (score 17):

Simply a normal grep which supports `Perl-regexp` parameter `P` will do this job.

```
$ echo 'abc blah
blah blah
def blah
blah blah' | grep -oPz  '(?s)abc.*?def'
abc blah
blah blah
def
```

`(?s)` called DOTALL modifier which makes dot in your regex to match not only the characters but also the line breaks.

Comment: When I try this solution the output does not end at 'def' but goes to the end of the file 'blah'

Comment: maybe your grep does not support `-P` option

Comment: This was the only that worked for me - tried all `sed` suggestions, but didn't go as far as installing grep alternatives.

Comment: `$ grep --version`:  `grep (GNU grep) 3.1` in the _Windows Git Bash_ has an option `-P, --perl-regexp` but `(?s)` doesn't seem to work there. It still shows the first line only. The same pattern with the same test string works on https://regex101.com/. Is there an alternative in the Git Bash? `sed`? (`sed (GNU sed) 4.8` here)

Comment: Do you know how to add [context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9081/grep-a-file-but-show-several-surrounding-lines) to the output? grep -1 doesn't work here.

Comment: It is not the Perl `-P` which does the trick here, but the `-z` which lets grep operate on the entire input at once instead of line by line! Try `grep -z 'abc.*def'`. (Actually, it now operates on pieces separated by the zero-bytes, which is usually absent in text files.)

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simpler approach using Perl:

```
perl -e '$f=join("",<>); print $& if $f=~/foo\nbar.*\n/m' file
```

or (since JosephR [took the `sed` route](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112149/22222), I'll shamelessly steal his [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112132/how-can-i-grep-patterns-across-multiple-lines#comment173884_112138))

```
perl -n000e 'print $& while /^foo.*\nbar.*\n/mg' file
```

#### Explanation

`$f=join("",<>);` : this reads the entire file and saves its contents (newlines and all) into the variable `$f`. We then attempt to match `foo\nbar.*\n`, and print it if it matches (the special variable `$&` holds the last match found). The `///m` is needed to make the regular expression match across newlines.

The `-0` sets the input record separator. Setting this to `00` activates 'paragraph mode' where Perl will use consecutive newlines (`\n\n`) as the record separator. In cases where there are no consecutive newlines, the entire file is read (slurped) at once.

#### Warning:

Do *not* do this for large files, it will load the entire file into memory and that may be a problem.

Comment: I don't know much about Perl, but wouldn't it need to be `my $f=join("",<>);`, strictly speaking?

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick only if you are in strict mode (`use strict;`). It's a good habit to get into, especially when writing larger scripts, but it's ooverkill for a little one-liner like this one.

Answer (score 8):

I solved this one for me using grep and -A option with another grep.

```
grep first_line_word -A 1 testfile | grep second_line_word
```

The -A 1 option prints 1 line after the found line. Of course it depends on your file and word combination. But for me it was the fastest and reliable solution.

Comment: alias grepp='grep --color=auto -B10 -A20 -i '    then cat somefile | grepp blah | grepp foo | grepp bar ... yes those -A and -B are very handy ... you have the best answer

Comment: This isn't super deterministic and it ignores the entire pattern in favor of just getting a different single line (just based on its proximity to the first line). It's better to tell the program to go however far it needs to go in order to get to some sort of pattern you're absolutely sure is the end of the text you're trying to match. For example if `testfile` gets updated such that `second_line_word` is on the third line, then not only are you now missing the first line (due to your second `grep`) but you're not missing the line that started showing up inbetween the two.

Comment: This would be a good enough MO for ad hoc commands where you really do just want a single line in output you already understood though. I don't think that's what the OP is after though and you could probably also just copy/paste at that point due to it being ad hoc.

Answer (score 6):

Supppose we have the file **test.txt** containing :

```
blabla
blabla
foo
here
is the
text
to keep between the 2 patterns
bar
blabla
blabla
```

The following code can be used :

```
sed -n '/foo/,/bar/p' test.txt
```

For the following output :

```
foo
here
is the
text
to keep between the 2 patterns
bar
```

Answer (score 4):

The grep alternative [sift](http://sift-tool.org) supports multiline matching (disclaimer: I am the author).

Suppose `testfile` contains:

```
<book>
  <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>
  <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
  labore  et dolore magna aliqua</description>
</book>
```

`sift -m '<description>.*?</description>'` (show the lines containing the description)

Result:

```
testfile:  <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
testfile:  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
testfile:  labore  et dolore magna aliqua</description>
```

`sift -m '<description>(.*?)</description>' --replace 'description="$1"' --no-filename` (extract and reformat the description)

Result:

```
description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
  labore  et dolore magna aliqua"
```

Comment: Very nice tool. Congratulations! Try to include it in distributions like Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is with Perl.  e.g. here's the contents of a file named `foo`:

```
foo line 1
bar line 2
foo
foo
foo line 5
foo
bar line 6
```

Now, here's some Perl which will match against any line that begins with foo followed by any line that begins with bar:

```
cat foo | perl -e 'while(<>){$all .= $_}
  while($all =~ /^(foo[^\n]*\nbar[^\n]*\n)/m) {
  print $1; $all =~ s/^(foo[^\n]*\nbar[^\n]*\n)//m;
}'
```

The Perl, broken down:

- `while(<>){$all .= $_}` This loads the entire standard input in to the variable `$all`
- `while($all =~` While the variable `all` has the regular expression...
- `/^(foo[^\n]*\nbar[^\n]*\n)/m` The regex: foo at the beginning of the line, followed by any number of non-newline chars, followed by a newline, followed immediately by "bar", and the rest of the line with bar in it. `/m` at the end of the regex means "match across multiple lines"
- `print $1` Print the part of the regex that was in parenthesis (in this case, the entire regular expression)
- `s/^(foo[^\n]*\nbar[^\n]*\n)//m` Erase the first match for the regex, so we can match multiple cases of the regex in the file in question

And the output:

```
foo line 1
bar line 2
foo
bar line 6
```

Comment: Just dropped by to say your Perl can be shortened to the more idiomatic: `perl -n0777E 'say $& while /^foo.*\nbar.*\n/mg' foo`

Answer (score 2):

If we want to get the text between the 2 patterns excluding themselves.

Supppose we have the file **test.txt** containing :

```
blabla
blabla
foo
here
is the
text
to keep between the 2 patterns
bar
blabla
blabla
```

The following code can be used :

```
 sed -n '/foo/{
 n
 b gotoloop
 :loop
 N
 :gotoloop
 /bar/!{
 h
 b loop
 }
 /bar/{
 g
 p
 }
 }' test.txt
```

For the following output :

```
here
is the
text
to keep between the 2 patterns
```

How does it work, let's make it step by step

1. `/foo/{`          is triggered when line contains "foo"
2. `n`               replace the pattern space with next line, i.e. the word "here"
3. `b gotoloop`      branch to the label "gotoloop"
4. `:gotoloop`       defines the label "gotoloop"
5. `/bar/!{`         if the pattern doesn't contain "bar"
6. `h`               replace the hold space with pattern, so "here" is saved in the hold space
7. `b loop`          branch to the label "loop"
8. `:loop`           defines the label "loop"
9. `N`               appends the pattern to the hold space.
   Now hold space contains :
   "here"
   "is the"
10. `:gotoloop`      We are now at step 4, and loop until a line contains "bar"
11. `/bar/`          loop is finished, "bar" has been found, it's the pattern space
12. `g`              pattern space is replaced with hold space that contains all the lines between "foo" and "bar" that have saved during the main loop
13. `p`              copy pattern space to standard output

Done !

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed) [multiline](/questions/tagged/multiline) [loop](/questions/tagged/loop)

Comment: Well done, +1. I usually avoid using these commands by tr'ing the newlines into SOH and performing normal sed commands then replace the newlines.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E "pattern1|pattern2"
```

would list all lines matching with either `<pattern1>` or `<pattern2>`.

Comment: I think OP want to match two or more lines containing thoses 2 patterns, not a single line containing either or both patterns.

Comment: @Archemar Not only that but it's a useless use of cat. Also `egrep` is deprecated. It's only there for backward compatibility. Should use `grep -E`. Also `<` and `>` can in some contexts be important of course like word boundaries `\<` and `\>` so probably shouldn't use them in examples because some people might take them literally (so unless it's being searched for they should be left out - probably).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-z` switch to let grep separate the content by `\0` bytes instead of newline, which in usual text files never appear. This leads grep to take the entire file as input at once.

Unfortunately I don't know how to reference a newline, but `.` will match everything, including newline:

```
echo 'first
second
third' | grep -z 'second.third'
```

This will output the entire input, and highlight the two lines matching the pattern. If your system does not highlight the match in the output, add `-o` to see the match isolated from the rest.