# Get contents of a file from first instance to last instance of some arbitrary string

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, logs, less

How can I view in `less` from the first instance of some arbitrary string "foo" to the last instance?

This arbitrary string will be on most every line of the log. I don't want to do `grep "foo" bar.log | less` because it won't be on each line that's relevant.

Let's say the file is

```
1 Random junk I don't want to see
2 Care about (foo)
3 Care about (foo)
4 Care about
5 Care about (foo)
6 Other random junk I don't want to see
```

Unfortunately the lines I want to ignore do not follow a nice pattern, otherwise I could use just `grep -v 'insert pattern here'`.

I am wondering how to get the following into `less` somehow,

```
2 Care about (foo)
3 Care about (foo)
4 Care about
5 Care about (foo)
```

`grep "foo" bar.log | less` will not work because it ignores line 4, which is one I care about.

Comment: you say "don't want to grep" but you tagged sed and grep; are you opposed to calling `sed` before `less`?

Comment: So you want an interactive `grep`, one where you only get shown one result at a time and you can switch between them?

Comment: @Jeff I don't mind at all, I just tagged with `grep` and `sed` because they seemed like the tools that would be able to do this.

Comment: This has been asked before more than once - here's just an example: [How can I “grep” patterns across multiple lines?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112132) so in your case `pcregrep -M  'foo.*(\n|.)*foo' infile`

Comment: @phk no, that's not what I meant, I've updated with an example.

Comment: Ok, then it might be related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20096639/awk-or-sed-to-print-text-between-the-first-occurance-of-a-pattern-and-the-last-o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `awk` you can do:

```
awk '/foo/{print b$0;b="";x=1;next} x{b=b$0"\n"}' bar.log | less
```

When a `foo` appears, it prints buffer (`b` variable) and current line, and clears the buffer.

Otherwise, but only if `foo` already appeared (`x` variable) it buffers current line.

Comment: Both this and @Stephane 's solution work. How do these stop on the last `foo`?

Comment: @CaptainMan only when `foo` appears, the lines since last `foo` are printed.

Answer (score 1):

It takes some careful shell quoting, but you *could* use the scriptable editor `ed` for this:

```
printf '%s\n' "/foo/ka" "??" "'a,.w "'!less' q | ed -s file
```

This sends four commands to `ed`:

1. `/foo/ka` -- searches (from the beginning of the file) for the pattern foo; at that first match, set a mark named `a`.
2. `??` -- repeat the search, but going backwards, wrapping around the end of the file; the important byproduct here is that it sets the current line to that (last) match.
3. `'a,.w !less` -- from the mark named `a` through the current line (`.`), write those lines to the shell command (`!`) `less`.
4. `q` -- quit ed.

You'll need to exit `less` gracefully (`q`) in order for `ed` to exit. This solution assumes that the pattern exists at least once in the file, otherwise the searches will fail and you'll get three `?`'s before `ed` exits.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to use grep to exclude matching lines, rather than include them? If so, try: `grep -v "Don't care about"`

Comment: Unfortunately not all the lines I want to skip have a nice pattern. I made them all say that in the question to make it a little more clear what I asking for. In reality this is about getting the "subsection" of the logs for a specific transaction. Many (but not all) of the lines relevant have the transaction's ID. Some log messages span multiple lines. That's why I wanted to get everything between the first and last instead of just reversing the filter. I will update the question to make this more obvious.