# Regex pattern with grep for expression2 AFTER expression1

Tags: ubuntu, grep, regular-expression

I am trying to find which of a bunch of HTML files have a heading with the word Agent with the name of a particular agent anywhere after that heading.

So typically something like

```
<h3>Agent</h3>
<p>Blah blah blah </p>
<p>Their agent is XYZ Corp.</p>
```

should be found

But I cant guarantee any regularity on markup or content between the heading and the instance of XYZ Corp. So in something like DOS I might search for 'Agent*XYZ' meaning

```
-match the string 'Agent'
-followed by anything
-followed by the string 'XYZ'
```

How do I write that in grep on Ubuntu?
I have tried

```
grep -lc 'Agent*XYZ' *.html
grep -lc 'Agent.*?XYZ' *.html
```

both without success. I can find the pattern manually in more than one of the files, so I know it exists.

TIA

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I “grep” patterns across multiple lines?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112132/how-can-i-grep-patterns-across-multiple-lines?)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems good for your target:

```
$ cat d2.txt
<h3>Agent</h3>
<p>Blah blah blah </p>
<p>Their agent is XYZ Corp.</p>

$ grep -i 'agent' d2.txt #-i = ignore case. By default grep returns lines containing agent followed by anything or even alone
<h3>Agent</h3>
<p>Their agent is XYZ Corp.</p>

$ grep -iE 'agent.*XYZ' d2.txt #match agent followed by XYZ
<p>Their agent is XYZ Corp.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `h3` heading always occurs on a line separate from the name of the agent, `sed` seems to be able to do what you ask.

Given the input file

```
some data
at the top
<h3>Agent</h3>
<p>Blah blah blah </p>
<p>Their agent is XYZ Corp.</p>
some data
at the bottom
```

the command

```
sed -n '\#<h3>Agent</h3>#,/XYZ/p' input.html
```

will generate

```
<h3>Agent</h3>
<p>Blah blah blah </p>
<p>Their agent is XYZ Corp.</p>
```

The `sed` command will output anything between the lines matching the two regular expressions `<h3>Agent</h3>` and `XYZ` (inclusively).  The funky looking `\#...#` that is delimiting the first regular expression is just how to use a custom delimiter. I did it that way rather than escaping the `/` in the pattern.