# How to grep a string that contains spaces and line breaks

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I was wondering if it's possible to use the grep command to pick out a string that contains spaces and line breaks, e.g.:

```
Hello
I
am
here right now
```

I'm still very new to regexps and using the command line in general (this is my second day of learning this), so my attempt was this:

```
grep H[\s\S]*w <filename>
```

I thought that [\s\S] would give you any character, including spaces and line breaks (unlike .), but it didn't work.

I use the terminal on my Mac OS (not sure if that makes a difference).

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112134/117549

Comment: you only need to use `-Poz` switches like `grep -Poz "H[\s\S]*w" infile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` works on lines, so, *"you can't do that"*; but, when I need to do something like that on `bash`, and I *don't want to*/*can't* use `perl` or alike (or, honestly, I just want to use `grep`) I do something like this:

```
tr '\n' '\a' < <filename> | grep --only-matching Hello$'\a'I$'\a'am$'\a'here\ right\ now | tr '\a' '\n'
```

`tr` translates chars; here, you are 'translating' *new lines* to *bell ascii char* *[hex code \x07 or '\a']*, then process that on `grep` (note that `grep` sees a long one line string, with *bell ascii chars* instead of *new line* chars), and then, back to 'normal', translating *bell ascii chars* to *newline*.

there is no need to use *bell ascii char*: you can use any char that doesn't appear in your file; in my case, it's just that I like the number seven and, usually, a text file doesn't contain any *bell ascii chars*

BTW: the `$'\a'` is [*Bash ANSI-C Quoting*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help! Is it possible to generalise this command to other strings than this specific one? E.g. all strings that start with 'hello' and end with 'now'?

Comment: The reason I ask is because I unsuccessfully tried it with:

'tr '\n' '\a' < <filename> | grep Hello.*here | tr '\a' '\n''

(It still gives me the full text, not just the part up to 'here').

Comment: It is perfectly possible, and your try is correct; you just only forgot the `--only-matching` flag in your `grep` command; by default, `grep` print all matching lines *(the full line)*: here, when you do `tr '\n' '\a' < <filename>`, you are sending *the one-line version* of your file to `grep`, so, from `grep`'s perspective, the file has one big line, thus, any match will print the full big line, i.e., your entire file. With the `--only-matching` flag, your are saying to `grep`: *hey, don't print the full matching line, just the matching chars*

Comment: You're welcome; consider to mark my answer as the one resolved your question

Comment: Of course, done :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -re 's/(.*)(H\w+\n)(.*w\n)(.*)/\2\3/' test.txt
```

With a test.txt file containing:

```
Something 
Hello
I
am
here right now
Something else
```

Tested with `sed (GNU sed) 4.4`. 
You can install GNU sed on macOS via Homebrew
Default sed on macOS is BSD sed, some options are slightly different.

Cheers,