# Searching match of multi-line regex in files (without pcregrep)

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression

### Question:

**How could I find matches of a multi-line regular expression in files, without pcregrep?**

I need to find/print the position of each occurrence.

Unfortunately, pcregrep is not present and I have no rights to install it. Other alternatives are `grep` `perl` `sed` `python` etc.

An example of regular expression to search is:

```
Text\nLine
```

### Context:

A script provides hundreds MB of structured text in a few tens of files, but unfortunately some lines are missing (due to many reasons). I do need to check where those lines are missing, thus searching for the sequence of the previous and following lines.

```
Text
Missing //this line is sometimes missing.
Line
```

### EDITED:

Possible input

example.txt

```
Text
Missing
Line

Text
Missing
Line

Text
Line

Text
Missing
Line
```

Possible output:

> example.txt, line 10

Some of the tries with no success:

```
pcregrep 
    # command not found
apt-get install pcregrep 
    # no permission, no su credentials, distro don't provide pcregrep, outdated sources, customer does not want changes on the serve, etc.
sed -r 's#(Text\nLine)#\1#' ./* 
    # print all lines, not only matches, no indication of file or line, etc.
grep 'Text\nLine' ./* 
    # Does not works on multi-lines
sed -n '/Text/,/Line/{p}' ./* 
    # Not the same regex, does not indicate result lines, etc.
```

Comment: Are you sure your file is Unix format and is not using /n/r as line terminator

Comment: Yes, I am sure. But in any case, it's not difficult to add `Text\r?\nLine`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiline pattern match using sed, awk or grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10226/multiline-pattern-match-using-sed-awk-or-grep)

Comment: @Kiwy This is not a duplicate other than that the solution that Adrian envisages happens to correspond with the title of the proposed dupe. The actual solution does not require a multiline regular expression. Also, the answers in the proposed dupe does not solve the given issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unix tools are most often line-oriented, and there is therefore no way to apply a regular expression over several lines of input using the standard toolbox.

`sed` can be made to process the file in such a way that it's able to detect the lines you are looking for, but we do this strictly using operations on individual lines:

```
$ sed -n '/^Text/{N;/^Text\nLine/=;D;}' file
10
```

This `sed` script looks for the string `Text` at the start of a line.  When found, it appends the next line to its buffer with a `\n` in-between.

If the buffer now matches `^Text\nLine` then the current line number is outputted using the `=` command in `sed`.  The line number outputted is that of the `Line` line in the file.

Note that while the second regular expression appears to match across a newline in the file, it does not.  It matches across a newline in its internal buffer, which we put there using the `N` command when we read the next line from the file.

You would probably use this in a loop if you want to apply it to multiple files:

```
for name in pattern; do
    printf 'Processing %s...\n' "$name"
    sed -n '/^Text/{N;/^Text\nLine/=;D;}' "$name"
done
```

where `pattern` would be an ordinary filename globbing pattern that matches the files that you are interested in.

Comment: Seem the N has difficulties with multiple files, but I may iterate the directory with a bash loop.

Comment: @AdrianMaire What difficulties? The fact that the line numbers are not reset between files? If you're using GNU `sed`, try `sed -s -n ...`.  But using a loop would be better as you would then be able to tell what lines refers to what files.

Comment: @Kiwy The answers to your proposed dupe are less than helpful in this instance.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks! I forgot that the user supplied dummy text.

Answer (score 1):

If `vim` is installed, you could use it in `ex` mode as:

```
vim -e -s -c 'argdo g/^Text\nLine/#' -c q ./*.txt
```

See also the `z` command to give context.

```
vim -e -s -c 'argdo g/^Text\nLine/z#.5' -c q ./*.txt
```

That doesn't print the file names though. A not very efficient `perl` approach could be:

```
perl -l -0777 -ne 'while (/Text\nLine/g) {
   print "$ARGV, line " . ++(() = $` =~ /\n/g)}' ./*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 perl -ne 'eof and $. = 0 or /^Text/ && ($_ .= <>) =~ /^Line/m && print "$ARGV: $.\n"' ./*
```

This will print the file name alongwith the line number where the match occurred.

Also, the line counter ($.) is reset upon reaching eof of each file.