# how to display grep with multiple line

Tags: bash, shell-script, solaris

I have the following code:

```
int val

nameof_function();
```

above code is in this file filename.txt
I try to find that sequence of lines in a file using

```
grep "int val.*\n.*(" filename.txt
```

but it is not working with multiple line.

I have also tried

```
awk '/int val/,/\(/' filename.txt
```

Here i am not getting file name in output

If I am using `grep` I can find file name in output but not ble to search muliple line

I need an output that looks like this:

```
filename.txt:int val nameof_function
```

Please any one help me

Comment: Fix formatting and reword your question - it's hard to say what are you asking about.

Comment: i need to grep pattern with multiple line @Arkadiusz

Comment: or awk with file name

Comment: Personally I'd use `pcregrep` with the `-M` switch - however if that's not an option, see [Searching match of multi-line regex in files (without pcregrep)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449039/searching-match-of-multi-line-regex-in-files-without-pcregrep). You can access the current filename in `awk` using the `FILENAME` builtin variable.

Comment: I tried to edit your post in a way that is more easy to understand, but ultimately it remains unclear e.g. what you mean by "Here i am not getting file name". Also, are you sure that the input is correct? It looks like C, but the `int val` statement is not terminated with a `;` for example.

Comment: i need to search for all directory that time i need file name and the function @steeldriver

Comment: please check now i have edited @AdminBee

Comment: Ok, now I understand the problem very well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if the source files contain the function separate by a line all you need to do is adjust the output of grep so it finds the `int val` and output the content 2 lines below also.

it would be something like this

```
grep -A 2 "int val" *.txt
```

Comment: Before ( symbol o need the value .. I can't go for two line .it will be bigger work .any other way for upto particularly take value with directors.@banjosa'a